# Increment positive numbers and decrement negative number all by 1

Tags: haskell

Declare the type and define a function that takes a list of numbers and returns a list that all the positive elements are incremented (increased by one) and negative numbers are decrement (subtracted by one). Also if there are 0 in the list it would be eliminated.

For example     fun [2, -4, 0, 66, -1]  would returns   [3, -5, 67, -2]

I've tried (++) between the two filter and map statements and zipWith (++)

Here is the code I have which gives a compile error.

```
incDec (x:xs) = map (+1) $ filter (>0) (x:xs) (++)
                map (-1) $ filter (<0) (x:xs)
```

Comment: Please post the error.  (always)

Answer (score 4):

`$` is going to bind looser than any other operator, so you need explicit parentheses. Also, you don't need to deconstruct the list since you're just putting it back together (the `x:xs` pattern is unnecessary and breaks your function on the empty list)

```
incDec xs = (map (+1) $ filter (>0) xs) ++
            (map (subtract 1) $ filter (<0) xs)
```

(See [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:subtract) for why I use `subtract` and not `-`  above)

However, this still doesn't do what you want. Since you're filtering and mapping twice, you're going to end up with all the positive numbers at the beginning and the negatives at the end, so you lose the original order of the list. Instead, we'll use [`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap), which can be used as a sort of hybrid filter / map.

```
incDec :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
incDec = concatMap go                  -- Do the map / filter combination
    where go x = case x `compare` 0 of -- Compare the number to 0
                   LT -> [x - 1]       -- If negative, subtract one
                   GT -> [x + 1]       -- If positive, add one
                   EQ -> []            -- If zero, eliminate
```

Example usage:

```
*Main> incDec [2, -4, 0, 66, -1]
[3,-5,67,-2]
```

Comment: There is a somewhat tidier solution by splitting the problem up into two parts and composing those, instead of doing it all at once. `incDec = map (\x -> x + signum x) . filter (/= 0)`. To get very fancy you could replace the lambda with `((+) <*> signum)` - normally I'm not a fan of `<*>` for functions, but here it's almost readable: "add the signum".

Comment: I really appreciate the help everyone. This one was really doing my head in.